# Internet Explorer 11 and developer mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web

Internet Explorer 11 works right when the developer mode is turned on and works wrong when the developer mode is turned off. 
I have a Web application which is written on Java (server) and HTML/CSS/JavaScript (client). When I use a breakpoint then the application stops on it and (for example) Chrome waits when execution will be continued. Next data refreshes in Chrome after the breakpoint.
IE 11 does the same in the developer mode. But when I turn off the developer mode, the application doesn't stop on the breakpoint and data doesn't change in IE 11.
How can I fix this behavior in IE?
Thank you.

```
<tr>
       <td colspan="3" class="table_colour_four left">
         <button id="findSigner" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button">
           <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick">

             pane = dijit.byId("signer.list");
             pane.href = "/wispa/adm/main/SignerList.do?" + getAttrString();
             pane.refresh();
           </script>
           Найти
         </button>
       </td>
     </tr>
```

Comment: Add some code, please?

Comment: Sounds like you have a race condition. You can try and verify this by introducing a short delay at the point where a breakpoint was beneficial.

Comment: @OscarPaz This is problem code: `<tr>
       <td colspan="3" class="table_colour_four left">
         <button id="findSigner" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button">
           <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick">
   
             pane = dijit.byId("signer.list");
             pane.href = "/wispa/adm/main/SignerList.do?" + getAttrString();
             pane.refresh();
           </script>
           Найти
         </button>
       </td>
     </tr>`

Comment: @RuudHelderman I debug my application in single user mode.

Comment: @Сергей A single user is bad enough in JavaScript; a breakpoint can easily cause events to be handled in a different order. As for the code, please do not use comments for that; edit and improve your question instead.